# setting up local drone server: Unable to login. Registration is closed

Tags: github, oauth, docker, access-denied, drone.io

I'm trying to set up a [local drone.io server](https://github.com/drone/drone) for CD with my github account. I'm using the official docker container. The setup instructions says to [add an application in github settings](http://readme.drone.io/setup/github.html) to get the client id and secret needed for drone github remote configuration, which I have done, the only difference from official docs is that I see the "Register new application" on the "Developer Applications" and not on "Authorized Applications", I hope it's the same. Then, I have defined the environment variables:

```
REMOTE_DRIVER=github
REMOTE_CONFIG=https://github.com?client_id=${client_id}&client_secret=${client_secret}
```

Replacing the client id and secret with my own. Then I bring the container up and try to login, I get redirected to github's authorization page, I authorize it and when redirected back I get this error:

> Unable to login. Registration is closed.

And the redirected URL is:

http://drone.myserver.com/login?error=access_denied

I really don't have a clue on what could possible be missing/misconfigured, the same setup works with the bitbucket remote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the problem. Browsing drone issues I found [this one](https://github.com/drone/drone/issues/993) that mentions that I need to add *open=true* to the query string so drone is able to create the github application.

Comment: Where do you put the configuration?

Comment: There's no configuration file, you just need to devine the necessary enviroment variables as mentioned on the OP.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Could you let me know where you set the ope=true config? Do I need to setup this environment variable before running the docker container? Or do I need to set it up inside the container os?

Answer (score 0):

If you get access_denied in web drone

This is docker-compose and answer -> DRONE_OPEN=true:


   `version: '2'
   services:
      drone-server:
        image: drone/drone:0.7
    ports:
      - 80:8000
    volumes:
      - ./drone:/var/lib/drone/
    restart: always
    environment:
     - DRONE_GITLAB=true
     - DRONE_GITLAB_CLIENT=change_value
     - DRONE_GITLAB_SECRET=change_value
     - DRONE_GITLAB_URL=https://gitlab-01example.com
     - DRONE_SECRET=change_value
     - DRONE_GITLAB_SKIP_VERIFY=true
     - DRONE_DEBUG=true
     - DRONE_OPEN=true
  drone-agent:
    image: drone/drone:0.7
    command: agent
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - drone-server
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    environment:
      - DRONE_SERVER=ws://drone-server:8000/ws/broker
      - DRONE_SECRET=change_value
      - DRONE_GITLAB_SKIP_VERIFY=true`